# Problema ao executar projeto asp.net mvc no visual studio 2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

Tenho um projeto em asp.net mvc 5 que precisei passar pro mvc 4, então criei outro projeto asp.net mvc 4, copiei todas as pastas do outro projeto, as referências tal e dei um build e não retorna nenhum erro, mas ao executar o projeto abre todo em branco. Como arrumar este erro ?

Minha View:

```
@section featured {
    <section class="featured">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <h3>Seja bem-vindo. Informe seu login e senha do portal. </h3>
            <div id="loginPrincipal">
                @if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                   <text>
                        Seja bem vindo @HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name <a href="/Conta/LogOff">Sair</a>
                   </text>
                }
                else{
                    {
                        using (Html.BeginForm()){
                            <text>
                                <label>Login: @Html.TextBox("login")</label> 
                                <label>Senha: @Html.Password("senha")</label>
                                <label><input type="submit" value="Entrar" /></label>
                            </text>
                          }
                    }
                }
                <p class="msgErro">
                    @ViewBag.Message
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>    
}
```

Comment: Vai ver a View que ele exibe está em branco :]

Comment: @PauloHDSousa não está não. :S

Comment: Tem como postar um print da view que abre e do action.

Comment: @PauloHDSousa vou colocar o código.

Comment: Você poderia colocar seu projeto no GitHub e fornecer um link para que possamos examiná-lo?

Comment: Nossa rs, como faço isso @CiganoMorrisonMendez ?

Comment: @AndreeH Entra aqui que te explico: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25342/c-asp-net-asp-net-mvc-entity-framework-etc